# Why a vector constructor takes only last value of the parameter when using in unordered_map emplace?

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map, emplace

I'm trying to implement unordered_map> with using unordered_map::emplace

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    unordered_map<char,vector<int>>  amap;
    amap.emplace('k',(2,9));
    for(auto i : amap['k']){
    cout << i;
    }

}
```

I expected output as "99" because I constructed the vector with (2,9).
but actual outcome was "000000000"  which the emplace constructed vector as  (9), 0 being default and 9 as number of ints.  I played around little more with other parameter values and realized the emplace only took last value in vector parameter.  Why is it?

I can still accomplish the goal by doing

```
vector<int> v(2,9);
amap.emplace('k',v);
```

but just wondering why, and save one line of code.

Answer (score 4):

```
amap.emplace('k',(2,9));
```

Here `(2,9)` is just comma separated values. Where everything before `,` is ignored.
So it is like

```
amap.emplace('k', (9));
```

`gcc` even throws a warning

> warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

You can use the below

```
amap.emplace('k', vector<int>(2,9));
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(2,9)` is using [the built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), and the result of that is `9`.

You need to provide a proper `std::vector` object, as in `std::vector<int>(2, 9)` instead.